# How to make sure at least 1 checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi I am making some sort of quiz application and I want to make sure the user checks at least 1 check box.

I am creating the the check boxes like this:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    arrGroup = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < question.length ; i++) 
        {
            if(question[i].multichoice == true)
            {               
                TextView title2 = new TextView(this);
                title2.setText(question[i].questionName);
                title2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                mLinearLayout.addView(title2);

                for(int zed = 0; zed < question[i].answers.length; zed++) 
                {               
                    final CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
                    box.setText(question[i].answers[zed].answer);
                    box.setId(zed);                     
                    mLinearLayout.addView(box);
                    int flag = 0;
                    if(box.isChecked() == true)
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                    if(flag == 1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }                   
            }
            else
            {
                 // create text button
                TextView title = new TextView(this);
                title.setText(question[i].questionName);                   
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                mLinearLayout.addView(title);

                // create radio button
                final RadioButton[] rb = new   RadioButton[question[i].answers.length];
                RadioGroup radGr = new RadioGroup(this);
                // take a reference of RadioGroup view
                arrGroup.add(radGr);        

                radGr.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                radGr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {                   
                        checkQuestionsAnswer();
                    }

                });

                for (int j = 0; j < question[i].answers.length; j++) {
                    rb[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                    radGr.addView(rb[j]);
                    rb[j].setText(question[i].answers[j].answer);
                }
                mLinearLayout.addView(radGr);
            }
        }              
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I cant figure out how to make sure the user has checked at least 1 box.

Comment: keep ur checkbox refrence in list and iterate through object and check wether isChekced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your checkboxes to a list as you create them.  then use the

```
checkbox.isChecked()
```

routine in a loop to make sure at least 1 is checked.

Look here for the checkbox API

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

and here for a list:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html\

```
// Added List
List<Checkbox> ansList = new List<Checkbox>();

// YOUR CODE with the list addition
for (int i = 0; i < question.length ; i++){

    if(question[i].multichoice == true){

        TextView title2 = new TextView(this);
        title2.setText(question[i].questionName);
        title2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mLinearLayout.addView(title2);

        for(int zed = 0; zed < question[i].answers.length; zed++){

            final CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
            box.setText(question[i].answers[zed].answer);
            box.setId(zed);

            // Since a test, make sure no answer is checked
            box.setChecked(false);

            // Add the checkbox to YOUR list of boxes
            ansList.add(box);

            mLinearLayout.addView(box);                     

        }
    }
}


// Later you can check with this
boolean atLeastOne = false;
for (int i = 0; i < question.length ; i++){

    if(question[i].multichoice == true){

        for(int zed = 0; zed < question[i].answers.length; zed++){

            if(ansList.get(zed).isChecked()) atLeastOne = true;                    

        }
    }
}

if(true == atLeastOne){
    // Do whatever you want to do if at least one is checked
}
```

I have NOT actually run or checked this code, but this should get you started, and it SHOULD work.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct way to make a list because I get this error: "Cannot instantiate the type List"

Comment: @user3182266 - Yeah, I had said that I hadn't tried it.  You have to define what type of data elements you need to put into the list.  Try the newly edited answer code, as it adds a "<Checkbox>" after the ansList declaration.

Comment: nope still getting an error "List<Checkbox> cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I think it should be ArrayList<CheckBox>()

Comment: I think I had the initial <CheckBox> in the incorrect spot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this method?

```
private boolean checkSelectionExists() {
    boolean selectionExists = false;
    selectionExists = (boolean) ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_checkbox1)).isChecked() ? true : false || 
            (boolean) ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_checkbox2)).isChecked() ? true : false || 
            (boolean) ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_checkbox3)).isChecked() ? true : false;

    return selectionExists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a flag and check every time, if a check-box is true make it = "1"and at last check whether it is "1" or not
Something like

```
Box[0]=name_of_first_Checkbox;
Box[1]=name_of_second_Checkbox;
// and so on..
int flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x ; i++){
            if(Box[i].isChecked())
            {               
                 flag =1;
            }
}

if(flag==1){
    //At least 1 box is checked
}
```

Comment: It is just an example you could put values instead of that, wait i will update my answer

Comment: @user3182266 There you go! If i clarified your doubt please put a tick by my answer

Comment: hmmm still nothing ... I dont knwo but I cant access the value flag after the first if statment

Comment: @user3182266 What do you mean you cannot access it? hmm? Did you declare it properly..? try making a new short program just to try this and then try to put this to your main code...

Comment: ok I do something like this I declare the value within the for loop and add 1 to flag after that I make an if statment if flag is 1 to print a toast and it doest print it

Comment: Could you mind showing me your code? or try to debug this i think it is a simple thing and you should be able to think why is that happening

Comment: @user3182266 See here, i just wrote a small c program showing this: http://ideone.com/1PO3bA

Comment: check out my update code and tell me if I am doing something wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47669/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-user3182266)

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a quick logic that come after reading your question,

- create a class level boolean variable named `isCheckButtonClicked`
- set by default its value to false
- Now on each checkbox's click event set its value to true
- Now at the final if you found it's value to true that means atleast one checkbox was cliked