# How to validate that at least one checkbox should be selected? and shows alert message

Tags: java, android

I want to validate at least one checkbox is selected.  Below is the code I'm using.

```
public classGejalaKariesGigiActivityextendsAppCompatActivity {

    Intent intentData;
    Button buttonSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gejala_karies_gigi);
        intentData = new Intent(GejalaKariesGigiActivity.this,HasilDiagnosaActivity.class);
        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonselesai1);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intentData);
            }

        });

    }

    public void selectItem(View view){
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkBoxgigiberlubang:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("gigi_berlubang","Gigi Berlubang");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("gigi_berlubang");
                }break;

                case R.id.checkBoxngilu:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("ngilu","Ngilu");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("ngilu");
                }break;

                case R.id.checkBoxadabercak:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("ada_bercak_hitam_pada_gigi","Ada Bercak Hitam Pada Gigi");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("ada_bercak_hitam_pada_gigi");
                }break;

                default:break;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Check this , it will work
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830099/how-to-make-sure-at-least-1-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check every checkbox whether it is Checked or not in if else statement.

```
if (chkbox1.isChecked()){
 //do your operation
}else if (chkbox2.isChecked()){
 //do your operation
}else if (chkbox3.isChecked()){
 //do your operation
}else{
 // show your alert dialog
}
```